# Mongodb C# driver, How to find Object with get only property using expression syntax

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

A domain object as following: (note that the Age property is get only)

```
public class Person
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return age;
        }
    }
    private int age;

    public Person(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

And this is my test initialize code:

```
    private static IMongoClient client;
    private static IMongoDatabase mongoDb;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Initialize(TestContext testContext)
    {
        client = new MongoClient();
        mongoDb = client.GetDatabase("test");
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Person>(cm =>
        {
            cm.AutoMap();
            cm.MapField("age").SetElementName("Age");
        });

        var person = new Person(10);
        person.Name = "abai";
        var collection = mongoDb.GetCollection<Person>("persons");
        collection.InsertOne(person);
    }
```

The following test will pass:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task FindPersonByNameTest()
    {
        var collection = mongoDb.GetCollection<Person>("persons");
        var result = await collection.Find<Person>(p => p.Name == "abai").ToListAsync();
        Assert.IsNotNull(result.FirstOrDefault());
    }
```

But this test will **fail**:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task FindPersonByAgeTest()
    {
        var collection = mongoDb.GetCollection<Person>("persons");
        var result = await collection.Find<Person>(p => p.Age == 10).ToListAsync();
        Assert.IsNotNull(result.FirstOrDefault());
    }
```

The exception message as following:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: {document}.Age is not supported.
Result StackTrace:  
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.GetFieldExpression(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateComparison(Expression variableExpression, ExpressionType operatorType, ConstantExpression constantExpression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateComparison(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate[TDocument](Expression`1 predicate, IBsonSerializer`1 parameterSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.ExpressionFilterDefinition`1.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.CreateFindOperation[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindAsync[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.FindFluent`2.ToCursorAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__16`1.MoveNext()
```

It seem like the get only Age property cause the exception. How can I use the expression syntax to find a Person object with get only property? thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be willing to get rid of the backing field and add a private setter to `Age` instead? If so, something like this might work:

```
public class Person
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }
    public Person(int age)
    {
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Then, in your ClassMap

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Person>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapProperty(p => p.Age);
});
```